# simply tooltip div - top position and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like help with http://jsfiddle.net/VmXU9/34/ .

```
$(".click").click(function() {
    var s = $(this).offset();
    left = s.left + $(this).width();
    $("#THREE").css({
        'opacity': 0.80
    });


    $("#THREE").css(s);
    $("#THREE").css({
        left: left
    });

});
```

I would like to modify the `top` and `left` positions of the yellow `<div>` to, for example, `left: 10px, top: -20px`. I would also like it to hide if I click outside it. How can I approach this?

Comment: where is the yellow div?

Comment: You have to click on the orange one to make it visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
$(function() {
   $(document).click(function(e)    {
        var $div = $("#yourDiv");

        // if the click was outside the div, hide it
        if(e.target != $div.get(0)) {
            $div.hide();
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Alter the top and left position of the yellow DIV?

Comment: i would like the YELLOW DIV was -20px top of  the current div clicked

Comment: use `$("#THREE").css({
        left: left,
        top: s.top - 20
    });`